# Alter field widget settings fields

Tags: 8

I'm trying to alter the settings fields displayed when you click on the cog icon on the "Manage form display" admin screen.

More specifically I want to alter fields set by another module through `hook_field_widget_third_party_settings_form`

I finally found the solution so i'll share it here as an answer.
It was not that hard, but I had to dig a bit into the core code in order to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form_id we want to alter is `entity_form_display_edit_form`
Because the settings fields are loaded through ajax, we first have to check if we are currently editing a field settings by checking  `$form_state->get('plugin_settings_edit')`
The fields we are looking for are then located at  `$form['fields'][FIELD_NAME]['plugin']['settings_edit_form']`

```
function fintech_form_entity_form_display_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $field_name = $form_state->get('plugin_settings_edit');
  if(!empty($field_name) && isset($form['fields'][$field_name]['plugin']['settings_edit_form'])) {
    $form['fields'][$field_name]['plugin']['settings_edit_form']['third_party_settings']['whatever_you_want_to_alter'] = '';
  }
}
```